# How to sync data in firestore with 2 device connect in 1 collection?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a collection in Firestore and there are 2 devices connect to it. (with the same account)
The collection has 3000 documents on it and 2 device backup data in the collection on SQLite database. Device1 is offline and device2 online. If device2 deletes one of the documents so how device1 can delete that document when it online again???

I know I can read all collection to solve it but it takes too many readings.
Sorry for my English. It's not good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Device1 is offline and device2 online. If device2 deletes one of the documents so how device1 can delete that document when it online again?

Being online, when "Device2" deletes a document, the delete operation will be seen almost instantly on the server. When "Device1" comes back online, the deleted document won't be on the server anymore. This means that the delete operation will also take place on "Device1". In other words, when "Device1" regains connectivity, il will have all documents from the collection in sync with the Firebase server and also up to date.

> I know I can read all collection to solve it but it takes too many readings.

You'll always be charged with a number of read operations that are equal to the number of documents that are returned by your query. So if you are using a CollectionReference rather than a Query that filters documents, you'll be charged with a number of read operations that is equal to the number of documents that exist in that collection.

Comment: So if device1 is online again, it will take only 1 read operation for deleted document or 3000 for all docs in collection???

Comment: If you aren't going to use a Query to filter the document according to a condition, which is the most appropriate way to handle this kind of situation, you'll have to pay 2999 read operations and a single delete operation, for the document that was deleted while offline. I think this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will clear your doubts, right?